# I cannot get this class to open another class/xml via button

Tags: java, android, xml

Every time I attempt to test this the app crashes when I hit the "Next" button (butHOURS button). I've tried redoing the XML's, looking over the code several times but I can't figure it out. Any help would be mighty appreciated. This is also the second class in a series of 5 and the first (main) class switches just fine to this class/xml layout.

```
package com.pewpew.studentadvisor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class Main2 extends Activity 
{

public Button butHOURS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    RadioButton hours1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hours1);
    RadioButton hours2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hours2);
    RadioButton hours3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hours3);
    RadioButton hours4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hours4);

    //Calculation based on ENROLLED question
    if (hours1.isChecked()){Main.calculation = Main.calculation + 1;}
    else{ if (hours2.isChecked())   {Main.calculation = Main.calculation + 2;   }
    else{ if (hours3.isChecked()) {Main.calculation = Main.calculation + 3; }
    else{ if (hours4.isChecked())   {Main.calculation = Main.calculation + 4;   }
    else{Main.calculation = 0.0;    }}}}


    //Get button to do button stuff like go to the next page
    Button butHOURS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butHOURS);
    butHOURS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Main2.this, Main3.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is the crash log

```
04-13 19:43:54.820: D/AndroidRuntime(26281): Shutting down VM
04-13 19:43:54.820: W/dalvikvm(26281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41548360)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.pewpew.studentadvisor/com.pewpew.studentadvisor.Main3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3417)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3378)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3588)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3556)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at com.pewpew.studentadvisor.Main2$1.onClick(Main2.java:43)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17254)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-13 19:43:54.830: E/AndroidRuntime(26281):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For anyone to find this later, my mistake was I had a typo in my AndroidManifest. >_<

Comment: Please post the detailed exception from logcat.

Comment: Ok will edit in one minute

Comment: Your problem might be that you'are not declaring the next Activity inside your Manifest file.

Comment: I though I did it correctly... should I post the manifest file as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already create a variable:

```
public Button butHOURS;
```

Then, you should use this variable as follows:

```
butHOURS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butHOURS);
```

You variable is useless in your code. However, the real problem is (as you can see in your LogCat):

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You should declare `Main3` Activity inside your Manifest as follows:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.pewpew.studentadvisor.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pewpew.studentadvisor.Main3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" /> 
    // other activities
</application>
```

Every Activity in your app needs to be declared in your Manifest file as above.

Comment: Sorry I just wrote out the wrong button, butHOURS is right and I removed the variable "public Button butHOURS;" and it still crashes. I actually didn't know I didn't need to declare it if it is used when finding the Id

Comment: See my updated answer. You didn't declare the activity in your manifest.

Comment: Oh my god... Filo thanks. I had it in the manifest as this: '            <activity
            android:name=".Mkain3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>'

Comment: Sorry I was simply trying to tell you I made a typo and discovered when I went to input what you wrote. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the attribute "public Button butHOURS;"

tks

Comment: Removed it but it still crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Manifest file. You should declare a new Activity like this:

`<activity android:name=".Main3"></activity>` under your 
`<application> ... </aplication>`